# Is there any way to see the GAQL when a GoogleAds custom report is built in the Google Ads UI?

Tags: google-ads-api

Built some custom reports in Google Ads API - Custom Reports.

I want to run the same "queries" in the Google Ads API.

Is there any way to save the "GAQL"  that the UI generated.

I can only export the data..  not the actual source query.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation offers GAQL queries for common UI reports: [click here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/query/cookbook)
For a custom report, there isn't a direction approach. You can try downloading it and observing the headers to see how to arrive at something similar. For example, the 'Ads' report with the 'Ad' column breaks down into about 90 columns once you download, hinting at the possibility of leveraging ad_group_ad resource.